# Can I fire event only when user finishes modifying Text widget?

Tags: java, swt, listener

I have an SWT `Text` control. I am trying to figure out how to listen for when the user is finished modifying the control, ie it is modified and then tabbed out of. I don't want my listener to be called every time a character changes in the textbox, and I don't want it to be called when the user traverses through the fields on the page. I only want it when the user modifies and then leaves the control.

I've looked at the various listeners available for the `Text` control, but unless I'm missing something, I don't see anything like this. Did I miss it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Save the text content to a variable on focus gain, then on focus lost compare it with the latest text - if different then text is modified else not.
- This listener will not be called on each and every character change.
- If you simply traverse the controls(with TAB key) then also you can detect whether text is changed or not.

```java
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.FocusEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.FocusListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class Snippet19 {
    private static String temp = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    final Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    text.setLayoutData(new GridData());
    text.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            if (temp.equals(text.getText())) {
                System.out.println("Text not modified");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Text conent modified");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            temp = text.getText();

        }
    });
    final Text text1 = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    text1.setText("chandrayya");
    text1.setLayoutData(new GridData());
    final Text text2 = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    text2.setText("chandrayya");
    text2.setLayoutData(new GridData());
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this idea. I got distracted into a different project, but when I get back to it, I'll definitely try this.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are looking for a `FocusListener`.  The `Text` control inherits `addFocusListener()` etc. from `Control`, so check the inherited methods section of its API docs.